# Improve concurrency performance in ASP .NET Core 3.1 and Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

At first I didn't know if my question is related to concurrency performance, but the scenario is I want to insert some events come from a PBX server and based on the type of each event, fill specific column value.

Events come too fast continuously and the duration between two events might be about 0.017s as below screenshot from inserted events.

[image]

The listener application is developed in ASP.NET 3.1 which has a class derived from .NET core Background Service class and `DBContext` is provided by Entity Framework Core 3.1.2.

In `ExecuteAsync` method event listeners have been provided. So in event listener for inserting events to database, I'm using .NET Core Service Provider scope to inject needed repository.

```
            using (var scope = _service.CreateScope())
            {
                var callStatRepo = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICallStatRepository>();
                var lastState = await callStatRepo.GetLastStateOfDevice(e.Channel.Name);

                var callTypeSb = new StringBuilder();

                if (lastState != null && String.Equals(lastState, "ANSWER",
                    StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    callTypeSb.Append(CallType.OUTCALL.Value);
                }
                else if (lastState != null && String.Equals(lastState, "InboundStarts",
                    StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    callTypeSb.Append(CallType.INBOUND.Value);
                }

                await callStatRepo.InsertCallStat(new RawCallStatRegisterViewModel
                {
                    HappenedAt = DateTime.Now,
                    Type = callTypeSb.ToString(),
                    Device = e.Channel.Name,
                    Number = e.Channel.Connected.Number,
                    State = e.Channel.State
                });

                callTypeSb.Clear();
            }

public async Task InsertCallStat(RawCallStatRegisterViewModel model)
{
    var rawCall = new DeviceState
    {
        HappenedAt = model.HappenedAt,
        Type = model.Type,
        Device = model.Device,
        Number = model.Number,
        State = model.State
    };

    _context.Entry(rawCall).State = EntityState.Added;

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Insert new call stat falis with this error : " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

The problem is around filling 'Type' column based on last previous 'State'. The condition for filling 'Type' is checking if last previous state was 'ANSWER' or 'Ringing'. But sometimes it cannot be figured it out what was the last state and leaves the Type column empty.

[image]

I think this problem is may related to inserting records too fast and don't know what is the solution for this. May I need to change the database type to any other type of databases such as MongoDB? And could it be the right solution? Are No-SQL databases faster than the SQL Server in concurrency?

Comment: Can you write the state to a cache also, then try to read it from there first (and only read it from the DB if it's not in the cache)? Seems that would be much faster

Comment: @crgolden writing events to cache might face a risk about getting too much memory because there are huge amount of events in just an hour but for a test case I would do it. Thanks.

Comment: You would only have to cache the last event, right? So the cache would only have to hold one object? (like `cache.get(e.Channel.Name)` or something)

Comment: Ditch entity framework and use ADO directly?

Comment: When "things" are consumed/processed concurrently, there is no guaranty of the order of execution. So only if the processed event have a sequence no or similar, you can do that.

Comment: Even if you get you code to do the process >10ms and it seems to work. Then try stress your CPU to 100% and execute you code again, then you will see a "new " order again.

Comment: SQL server is multi-threaded and there is no guarantee what the LAST operation was.  Date get store in random order and to get data in the same order every time you must use an OrderBy.